# Firebase, Swift - runTransactionBlock: Permission denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have encountered a problem while trying another users to star as runTransaction "Permission denied" by Firebase. I added below my Firebase security rules for posts and then swift transaction code.

What is my fault in this case? If I did first ".write" rule as "auth != null" It works for everyone. But I don't want this. I want to prevent other nodes, only starCounter and stars need to be changeable.

If someone shed light and explain, It would be great.

```
"posts": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$id": {
        ".write": "auth != null  && (
                   (!data.exists() && newData.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid) ||
                   (!newData.exists() && data.child('ownerID').val() == auth.uid) ||
                         root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid))",
        "starCounter": {
            ".write": "auth !== null"
        },
        "stars": {
            ".write": "auth !== null"
        },
      }
    },
```

And here is my Swift transaction code below..

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(self.post.postKey!)").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

      if var post = currentData.value as? [String: AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

          var stars : Dictionary<String, Bool>
          stars = post["stars"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
          var starCount = post["starCounter"] as? Int ?? 0

          if let _ = stars[uid] {

              // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
              starCount -= 1
              stars.removeValueForKey(uid)
              self.starBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "star-full"), forState: .Normal)
              self.starBtn.setTitle("unstar", forState: .Normal)

          }
          else {

              // Star the post and add self to stars
              starCount += 1
              stars[uid] = true
              self.starBtn.setBackgroundImage(self.starImageView!.image!, forState: .Normal)
              self.starBtn.setTitle("star", forState: .Normal)
          }

          post["starCounter"] = starCount
          post["stars"] = stars

          currentData.value = post

          DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(self.post.postKey!)").child("starCounter").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

              if let starCount = snapshot.value as? Int {
                  self.starCountLbl.text = "\(starCount)"
              }

          })

          return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)

      }

      return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
  })
```

#### Update:

I have a posts node like below. I want to handle “starCounter” and “stars” reachable (write and read) by everyone. But others only write by owner. I’m using runTransaction to do it using nearly same in [Save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#save_data_as_transactions). But I’m getting permission denied while trying star a post by another users (`auth.uid`) not only owner. So I couldn’t do both increase star counter with transaction and adding who in stars node.

```
posts
  post_id_0
    post_title
    post_description
    post_ownerID
    ...
    starCounter
    stars
     person_1: true
     person_2: true
     ...
  post_id_1
  ..
```

I have tried before security rules first advice (It’s an answer ~10m. before), but It didn't help, I couldn’t add new post. I don’t know exactly what I’m missing in security rules to do this in the same parent node.

**Reduced code below for above security rules..**

```
post_ref.child("\(self.post.postKey!)").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    if var post = currentData.value as? [String: AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        var stars : Dictionary<String, Bool>
        stars = post["stars"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
        var starCount = post["starCounter"] as? Int ?? 0
        if let _ = stars[uid] {
            starCount -= 1
            stars.removeValueForKey(uid)
        }
        else {
            starCount += 1
            stars[uid] = true
        }
        post["starCounter"] = starCount
        post["stars"] = stars
        currentData.value = post
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
    }
    return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
})
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here that accesses the database and it's not immediately clear to me which line is causing the problem. Can you reduce the code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks your attention, I detailed a little more my question. Could you check please?

Comment: Please **reduce** the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated again with reduced code above.

Comment: I just ran your last code snippet on an previously empty data location and it runs without problems.